# Transparency with reorderchild method in cocos2d for iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have problems with making transparend background of dynamically added objects to isometric tilemap in cocos2d. I enabled depth (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES in appdelegate) and after I add new sprite to tilemap with this code

```
CCSprite *zgrada1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"barakaTest.png"];
    [zgrada1 setPosition:[tileMap convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation]];
    float lowestZ = -(tileMap.mapSize.width + tileMap.mapSize.height);
    float currentZ = tilePos.x + tilePos.y;
    float z = lowestZ + currentZ - 1.5f;
    [tileMap addChild:zgrada1];
    [tileMap reorderChild:zgrada1 z:z];
```

I have one object properly added, but there is no transparency. Z-order (vertexz) is working good, but background is black. here is the screenshot:

http://oi43.tinypic.com/2zsb1xs.jpg

Comment: i seem to remember there exists a coupling between GL_DEPTH and setting projection to [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D]; Not certain it is related to your issue, but rings a bell.

Comment: I added these two lines in appdelegate.m:

    [director_ setDepthTest:YES];
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

and it's still the same

Comment: what version of cocos2d are you using ?

Comment: i'm using cocos2d 2.0

Comment: I'm using vertexz instead of reorderchild metod now and after adding this line of code: sprite.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache]programForKey: kCCShader_PositionTextureColorAlphaTest]; renderring is better, but it still has some distorted parts. here is the screenshot: http://oi41.tinypic.com/5ea6h1.jpg

Comment: same problem here.... did you get it solved???